# Set popover size to the size of presented controller's view

Tags: ios, swift

I need to make a universal popover for iPhone, adjusting its size to the size of the presented view. So I created a ViewController subclass to handle all the presentation logic:

```
class PopoverViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    var contentView = UIView()

    init(contentView: UIView, sourceView: UIView) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.contentView = contentView
        view = contentView
        preferredContentSize = view.bounds.size
        modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        guard let controller = popoverPresentationController else {return}
        controller.permittedArrowDirections = .up
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.sourceView = sourceView
        controller.sourceRect = sourceView.bounds
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

extension PopoverViewController: UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {
    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .none
    }
}
```

Its size and everything is fine then I set preferredContentSize a specific frame (like 320x260, etc)

[image]

But when I set it to a presented controller's view frame or bounds size, popover presents with default size:

[image]

I tried to check contentView frame by printing in and it turns out it comes with zero width and height. ContentView layout code:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .white
        addSubview(titleLabel)
        addSubview(contentLabel)
        titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(appearance.xlSpace)
            make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(appearance.xlSpace)
        }
        contentLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(titleLabel.snp.bottom).offset(appearance.lSpace)
            make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(appearance.sSpace)
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(appearance.xsSpace)
        }
        print("width: \(self.bounds.width), height: \(self.bounds.height)")
    }
```

Presentation code:

```
  func showInfo() {
        let view = PopupView()
        let controller = PopoverViewController(contentView: view, sourceView: contentView.infoButton)
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

How can I properly set my popover controller preferredContentSize to view frame size and make It universal to present any view that gets passed into controller?

Comment: Well there are 2 approaches,
1) Use TextView
2) label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.height + (Top Label font constraints)).isActive = true

Answer (score -1):

I believe the problem is that you are setting the `preferredContentSize` property too early.  Try doing it in `viewWillAppear` instead.  When init is called, I don't think everything has been properly set up and laid out yet.